# How to find issue in Django TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: django, django-templates

I cannot find issue that causing TemplateDoesNotExist.

`urls.py` in main project folder:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('quality.urls'))
]
```

`urls.py` in quality app:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', view.index, name='index')
]
```

[image]

And `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Comment: url(r'^$', views.index, name='index') - typo in views/view is not the issue where

Comment: Did you set the `TEMPLATES` in the `settings.py` correctly?

Comment: I didn't set there anything, I was following tutorial and nothing was set about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of setting `TEMPLATES`. This is telling `Django` where your `templates` folder is:

*settings.py*

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: This is the case. I had to specify app folder:'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'quality/templates')],

Comment: Yes, but I don't suggest you define parent folder `quality` since you may have multiple apps in your web app and each of them may have `templates` folder.

Comment: So I should move templates from app folder to project folder?

Comment: You can keep the `templates` folder for each application since you define your `BASE_DIR`.